# could not find js files in Django project

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I used python 3.7 in windows 10 to create a Django project.
setting.py:

```
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
LOGIN_URL = '/login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

[image]

I used superuser to create some normal user. But the normal user account could not login the website, and in the power shell, the below error occurs:

> [02/Nov/2020 13:33:03] "POST /login/?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 200 14278 Not
> Found: /login/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css [02/Nov/2020
> 13:33:04] "GET /login/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css
> HTTP/1.1" 404 19761 Not Found: /login/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js
> [02/Nov/2020 13:33:04] "GET /login/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js
> HTTP/1.1" 404 19713 Not Found:
> /login/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js [02/Nov/2020
> 13:33:04] "GET /login/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js
> HTTP/1.1" 404 19777 [02/Nov/2020 13:33:19] "POST /login/?next=/
> HTTP/1.1" 200 14278 Not Found:
> /login/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js [02/Nov/2020
> 13:33:19] "GET /login/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js
> HTTP/1.1" 404 19777 Not Found: /login/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js Not
> Found: /login/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css [02/Nov/2020
> 13:33:19] "GET /login/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css
> HTTP/1.1" 404 19761 [02/Nov/2020 13:33:19] "GET
> /login/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 19713 Not Found:
> /login/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js [02/Nov/2020 13:33:19] "GET
> /login/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 19712 Not Found:
> /login/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js [02/Nov/2020
> 13:33:19] "GET /login/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js
> HTTP/1.1" 404 19776

But I have checked that I do have their files in static folder:

[image]

[image]

I have tried to run python manage.py collect static but the error occurs:

> ```
>     raise ImproperlyConfigured("You're using the static files app "
> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the static files app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a
> ```
>
> filesystem path.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nL1jK.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MmBD.png)

login.html
{% load static %}

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}</title>

    <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
    <link href="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="{% static 'vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i"
          rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/sb-admin-2.css' %}"/>

</head>

<body class="bg-gradient-primary">

<div class="container">

    <!-- Outer Row -->
    <div class="row justify-content-center">

        <div class="col-12">

            <div class="card o-hidden border-0 shadow-lg my-5">
                <div class="card-body p-0">
                    <!-- Nested Row within Card Body -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-8 d-none d-lg-block bg-login-image"></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <div class="p-5">
                                <div class="text-center pb-5">
                                    <img src="{% static 'image/logo.png' %}" height="60px">
                                </div>
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <h1 class="h4 text-gray-900 mb-4">Welcome Back!</h1>
                                </div>
                                <form class="user" method="post">
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control form-control-user" name="username" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                                               placeholder="Username">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-user" name="password"
                                               placeholder="Password">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox small">
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck">
                                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck">Remember Me</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">
                                        Login
                                    </button>
                                </form>
                                <hr>
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <a class="small" href="forgot-password.html">Forgot Password?</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<script src="{% static 'vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js' %}"></script>

<!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
<script src="{% static 'js/sb-admin-2.min.js' %}"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you enabled admin in urls.py. Just check that your URL should be localhost:port/admin/login

Comment: From your image, seems like your static files arent in the default or conventionally used folder `static` but if you are using a different static files folder, make sure this is defined in the `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting

Comment: @AshishGupta Where should I add that?

Comment: @RedgrenGrumbholdt I have the static folder but in the console it keeps showing: /login/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 19761 Not Found, so I copy the vendor file from static folder to login folder

Comment: Copy the files from login folder to the static folder.

Comment: @RedgrenGrumbholdt I already copied , still the same problem

Comment: The weird thing is that URLs for static files do not start with `/static` prefix. Can you show the template for login page? I am interested how these links to static files are generated.

Comment: @EugenePrikazchikov I have just pasted the template for login page at the end of my question, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please follow steps [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) to make static files work. Judging from errors you posted, I guess that following is misconfigured:

1. Weird STATIC_URL value in settings. Looks like you have `STATIC_URL='/login/'`. Typically it should be set to `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`
2. Make sure that you store your static files in `static` folder within one of your apps. I.e. if you have an app named `bms`, then put your static files to `bms/static` folder. Django provides helpful [findstatic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#findstatic) command to help you understand where it is looking for given static file, for example: `python manage.py findstatic -v3 js/msp/table_header.js`
3. Please note that django serves static files by itself only if you use django's development server (`runserver` command) and only if you set `DEBUG=True` in settings. For serving static files in production environment, please see this [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/deployment/)

Comment: In my  setting.py,   STATIC_URL = '/static/'
LOGIN_URL = '/login'

Comment: I used Django development server,  and I have checked that there indeed are static files in bms/static folder

Comment: Can you try running findstatic command that I described in step 2? Do you see a listing of directories where django is looking for static files?

Comment: Also, you did not mention DEBUG setting. Did you check that it is set to True?

Comment: Debug is set to Ture in my case all the time as I am in debug process

Comment: python manage.py findstatic -v3 vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css
Found 'vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css' here:
  C:\Users\williamyangy\Desktop\Projects\2020\Textbook_DB\Dev\textbookdb\bms\static\vendor\fontawesome-free\css\all.min.css
Looking in the following locations:
  C:\Users\williamyangy\Desktop\Projects\2020\Textbook_DB\Dev\textbookdb\bms\static

Comment: Good, so django CAN find it! Then the issue must be wrong URLs in login page HTML. First, let's figure out proper URL. If STATIC_URL = '/static/', then try opening  http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css and see if it works. If it does not work, then double check values of STATIC_URL and DEBUG settings. The most robust way to check them is via manage.py shell command like this - python manage.py shell -c 'import django.conf; print(django.conf.settings.STATIC_URL)'

Comment: This link "127.0.0.1:8000/static/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css " could be open in my case.

Comment: when I run  python manage.py shell -c 'import django.conf; print(django.conf.settings.STATIC_URL)'
The result is "/static/"

Comment: OK, if /static/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css opens successfully, then static files are served ok, and the issue is in wrong links in login page. Inspect rendered HTML (via "View Page Source" functionality of the browser), check how links look like there and fix them in template. For troubleshooting you might want to replace "{% static ... %}" template tags with just hardcoded URLs and see if it helps.

Comment: I could not login to the login page, not sure if it arrives from this problem